# How to get the columns with count of the same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, count

I'm working on laravel have having trouble to get the count of how many people the users have sponsored the table is called `users` and the data looks like below.

```
|--------------|----------------  |-------------|
|      id      |    first_name    | sponsor_id  |
|--------------|------------------|-------------|
|       59     |    kaqefizew     |   NULL      |
|--------------|------------------|-------------|
|       68     |    fucifaxe      |   59        |
|--------------|------------------|-------------|
|       81     |    fepetora      |   59        |
|--------------|------------------|-------------|
|       82     |    kixys         |   81        |
|--------------|------------------|-------------|
```

And need output like below

```
|--------------|----------------  |------------------|
|      id      |    first_name    | sponsored_count  |
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       59     |    kaqefizew     |   2              |
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       68     |    fucifaxe      |   0              |
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       81     |    fepetora      |   1              |
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       82     |    kixys         |   0              |
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I tried using count clause

```
SELECT id, first_name, COUNT(sponsor_id) as sponsored_count FROM `users` GROUP BY id
```

But i'm getting wrong output like this below

```
|--------------|----------------  |------------------|
|      id      |    first_name    | sponsored_count  |
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       59     |    kaqefizew     |   0              |
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       68     |    fucifaxe      |   1              |
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       81     |    fepetora      |   1              |
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
|       82     |    kixys         |   1              |
|--------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Relationships

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{

public function sponsor(  ){
        return $this->belongsTo( User::class, 'sponsor_id', 'id' );
    }
}
```

Kindly help me solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Can you share more information about your models and their relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses a subquery:

```
select id, first_name,
    (select count(*) from mytable t1 where t1.sponsor_id = t.id) sponsored_count
from mytable t
```

You could also `left join` an aggregate query:

```
select t.id, t.first_name, t1.sponsored_count
from mytable t
left join (
    select sponsor_id, count(*) sponsored_count
    from mytable
    group by sponsor_id
) t1 on t1.sponsor_id = t.id
```

Comment: Greate Thank you so much can you help how i can acheive it laravel eloquent as i'm new to it.

Answer (score 0):

First, edit your relationship method to refer to Sponsor model as below:

```
public function sponsor(  ){
        return $this->belongsTo( Sponsor::class, 'sponsor_id', 'id' );
    }
```

You can count a relationship in eloquent using `withCount` static method.

```
$users=User::withCount('sponsor')->get();
```

Then you can get count by calling `$users->sponsors_count`